# change position of title of a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have create a horizontal colorbar, when I use `set_title("blabla")` this puts title up above the colorer. Is there anyway I can have title at the side of the colorbar. So instead of having the title above the x-axis have it by the side of the y-axis.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have the color bar aligned with the x-axis, or the title? (too many "it"s)

Comment: edited it, didn't even notice the poor english first time around, thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but instead of using `set_title` you could use the `set_ylabel` command as that would put the "title" by the side of the `y`-axis

```
 set_ylabel('blabla')
```

Alternatively you could use the [`position`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_position) attribute (`(0, 0) == (x=0, y=0)`)

```
 set_title('blabla', position=(0, 0))
```

but this wouldn't guarantee that the `colorbar` and `title` don't overlap.